# Tkinter multi GUI windows

Tags: python, tkinter

I have problem with the multi GUI windows when using Tkinter in python3.4. I have created two GUI windows. When the codes running, first GUI will appear,and the second will appear when "another" button clicked. but The entry box is empty, "10.10.10.20"should in it. I don't know why. Below is the python code.Is anyone could help me?

```
from tkinter import *

def kkk():

    tt=Tk()
    fram2(tt)

class fram1:
    def __init__(self,master):

        var = IntVar()
        menubar=Menu(master)
        filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=1)
        filemenu.add_command(label='file', command=lambda:print('file'))
        menubar.add_cascade(label='file', menu=filemenu)
        master.config(menu=menubar)

        Label(master, text="First").grid(sticky=E)
        Label(master, text="Second").grid(sticky=E)

        e1 = Entry(master)
        e2 = Entry(master)

        e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

        checkbutton = Checkbutton(master, text='Preserve aspect', variable=var)
        checkbutton.grid(columnspan=2, sticky=W)

        button1 = Button(master, text='quit',command=master.destroy)
        button1.grid(row=2, column=2)

        button2 = Button(master, text='another',command=kkk)
        button2.grid(row=2, column=3)

class fram2:
    def __init__(self,t):

        t.title("IP address")
        t.geometry('500x100')

        self.frm = Frame(t)
        var_char = StringVar()
        Entry(self.frm, textvariable=var_char, width = 22, font =('Verdana',13)).pack(side=RIGHT)
        var_char.set('10.10.10.20')
        Label(self.frm, text = 'IP Address', font =('Arial',12)).pack(side=LEFT)      
        self.frm.pack(side =LEFT,anchor='nw')


root=Tk()
fram1(root)
mainloop()
```

Comment: Please ensure your code is indented 4 spaces; you can do this across a lot of text by highlighting it and clicking the {} button in the taskbar.

Comment: Just an offtopic comment, but it may be nice to use **kwargs or *args in functions where you might get more arguments than expected if you forget the exact number or order such as `__init__` otherwise it'd crash with too much args or similar error.

Comment: You are creating multiple `Tk` instances instead of using `TopLevel`s to make multiple windows.  `IntVar()` implies a default root `Tk` instance which is seperate from the one it is used in.